# Firebase Analytics google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled not working

Tags: flutter, analytics, reporting, firebase-analytics

i am using these versions for firebase analytics:

firebase_analytics: ^10.1.0
firebase_core: ^2.1.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.9

i have added

in application tag, after that its adding screen reporting on firebase dashboard,

Comment: can you share how are you implementing this? are you trying to disable screen reporting in your app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes, i want to implement disable screen reporting, any clue ?? i have added in application tag but not working, this tag...
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" android:value="false" />